# making shell program on bash and call files in program and change text

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have been instructed to make a javascript. after learning some shell script (very minimal). I have created the following.

```
for item in *
do
    if [ -f $item ]
    then 
        sed  's/test/open/g' file.sh
done
```

This program I believe looks for files within the folder I have placed this program in. And afterwards finds file.sh and replaces the word test with open, from what I understand from the sed (again forgive me if it is not true). How can I modify this so instead of one file this program looks through all of the .sh files in the program and finds the word test in all of them and replaces it with open. I'm sorry this is vague if so but this is all I have to work with.

Comment: This is really too vague

Comment: sorry what can I clarify\

Comment: Take the time to got to the help center and see what we expect from a good question. From what I currently read, there is absolutely no detail that could help me make a better answer than your "[you] have to use an if statement and grep and sed commands"

Comment: can you offer any guidance now please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is flawed in a few ways.

```
for item in * <--do the following action on every item in this directory
do

         if [ -f $item ]  <--if the item is a file then do this
         then 
                sed  's/test/open/g' file.sh  <-- replace "test" with "open" in the file - file.sh
          <--missing closing "fi" statement here
done
```

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but if you only want to replace every occurrence of test with open in the file: `file.sh` you should probably just do `sed 's/test/open/g' file.sh` otherwise if you want to replace it in every file do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
script=$(basename "$0")
for item in "/path/to/files/"*; do
    if [[ "$item" == "$script" ]]; then
        :
    elif [[ -f "$item" || "${item: -2}" = "sh" ]]; then 
        sed -i 's/test/open/g' "$item"
    fi
done
```

**EDIT**

If you aren't sure what you are doing you should be really careful with this script.  Make sure you point to the correct directory and be aware that you are just blanket modifying every file in it.

Comment: sed: couldn't open file test/open/g: No such file or directory. is the error that apppears
what I wish to do is in each .sh file replace the word test with open(provided each of the files have this word).

Comment: If you do `sed --version` what does it return?

Comment: it says 4.4....

Comment: for item in  /c/RB/* 
do
    if [ -f  $item ] 
 then 
      echo $item  &&
   sed -i 's,{connections.url},http://wsami250058-gyr:8080,g' $item
  fi
done

Comment: that was the final program required thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

**Let us first clear up some misunderstandings:**

What does your script currently do? It iterates through each item in the directory where the script is *executed* (not where it is placed). Then it looks for each item, whether it is a file or not. If it is a file, then it opens the file `file.sh` and does replacement stuff using `sed`.

**What it is supposed to do:**

Instead of open `file.sh` after each true `if` statement it should open the actual item.

**What you can change to accomplish that:**

Replace `file.sh` in the `sed` command by `$item`

Comment: Instead of a simply downvoting the answer I would appreciate constructive criticism to improve the answer. Thank you.